# How to copy some bits of an int in to a char buffer

Tags: c, microcontroller

I am trying to copy some values from `uint32_t to my uint8_t.`

I have `uint8_t tx_buff_id[3];`

```
sprintf(tx_buff_id, "%X", rx_dataframe.id);// rx_dataframe.id is H'0000005b
```

I am getting in my buffer `tx_buff_id[3] at [0] '5' [1] 'B' [2] '.'`// Hex equivalent of these `0x35,0x42,0x00`

What i want in my buffer is `tx_buff_id[3] at [0] '0' [1] '5' [2] 'B'` // Hex equivalent of these `0x30,0x35,0x42`

Source sending values like this only, and i don't have any influence on the source otherwise i could receive the values in the identical format.

Comment: `sprintf(tx_buff_id, "%03X", rx_dataframe.id);`

Comment: like @joop said and make the buffer larger to hold the terminating NULL char and other characters if the number is a true 32 bit (total 9 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

If you're building a string, or at least using string-formatting functions, use a `char` destination variable, not `uint8_t`. This is not "copying some bits", this is converting an integer to string.

It sounds like you want

```
char tmp[4];

sprintf(tmp, "0%X", rx_dataframe.id);
```

That will give you the string `"05b"`, i.e. it will prepend the character `'0'` that you say you want before the two digits of the hex number.

The `tmp` array must be length `4` since `sprintf()` will write a string terminator. Your code fails to respect this. Not sure where the period (`'.'`) comes from that you claim you see.

Comment: Sorry but please see the question again, i made an edit

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple loop, as shown in the example below:

```
uint8_t* ptr = (uint8_t*)&rx_dataframe.id;
uint8_t tx_buff_id[sizeof(rx_dataframe.id)];

// On a little-endian architecture
for (int i=0; i<sizeof(rx_dataframe.id); i++)
    tx_buff_id[i] = ptr[i];

// On a big-endian architecture
for (int i=0; i<sizeof(rx_dataframe.id); i++)
    tx_buff_id[i] = ptr[sizeof(rx_dataframe.id)-1-i];
```